# Convert 3-dimensional array to 2-dimensional array in C

Tags: c, arrays

In my C code I have this union:

```
volatile union {
          float a3d[32][4][3];
          float a2d[32][12];
} virial;
```

But I want to create two buffers, so that they will act as the above union:

1. `float my_virial_a3d[32][4][3];`
2. `float my_virial_a2d[32][12];`

So, how can I copy the data from my 3-dimensional buffer to the 2-dimensional, acting like a Union?

Comment: Are you looking for `memcpy`?

Comment: without memcpy. I want an algorithm for that problem.

Answer (score 1):

Easy - just threat both arrays as 1 dimensional plain float such (which their internal structure is in-fact):

```
#include <stddef.h>

((main))()
{
    float my_virial_a3d[32][4][3], my_virial_a2d[32][12];

    for(size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(my_virial_a3d) / sizeof(float); ++i)
        *((float*)my_virial_a2d + i) = *((float*)my_virial_a3d + i);

}
```